# I have an existing android project in which gen folder is missing. How can i run this project?

Tags: android

I I have an existing android project in which gen folder is missing. How can i run this project? Eclipse is give me following error.

Make the resources ID non constant. This is required to make an R java class that does not contain the final value but is used to make reusable compiledlibraries that need to access resources.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Bilal\Desktop\Lecture05\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist    Lecture05       Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to clean your project to make sure the R.java file is generated. If it does not create gen folder - create it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The Android Ressource Manager is responsible for creating the R.java file in the gen folder. This happens when the project is build, either automatically or via the "clean" command.

Check the Properties of the project to see if the Android Resource Manager is properly included as a Builder for this project. There should be four builders registered in the "Builders" section:

- Android Resource Manager
- Android Pre Compiler
- Java Builder
- Android Package Builder